# CQ5 DAM upload failure

Tags: aem, dam

I am trying to upload assets to CQ5 DAM using the dam admin screen. I am able to successfully upload files with sizes up to 5 MB. I am getting an error message "failed to upload the following file : " while uploading files with sizes greater than 5 MB. This happens in both HTML5 supporting browsers (FF) and non-HTML5 browsers (IE).

When I checked the POST request in the firebug console, I got an error message asking me to check the error logs in the server. Below is what i got in the error message,

*The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webuser@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.*

But when I searched the error logs, I couldn't find anything related to the failed uploads.

I searched over the internet but couldn't find any solution for this issue. Please let me know if anyone has faced the same issue and resolved it. Below is what I got when I checked the recent requests in OSGI console,

```
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Method=POST, PathInfo=/content/dam/test.createasset.html
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/content/dam/test.createasset.html resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=nt:folder, superType=null, path=/content/dam/test
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/dam/test', selectorString='createasset', extension='html', suffix='null'
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=nt:folder, superType=null, path=/content/dam/test)}
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=nt:folder, superType=null, path=/content/dam/test)} Using servlet com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.CreateAssetServlet
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/content/dam/test.createasset.html handled by Servlet=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.CreateAssetServlet
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Applying Requestfilters
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.aio.aiofilter.AioImageFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.bc.ImageFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (method does not match)
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Applying Componentfilters
  0 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
  1 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
  1 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_START{com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.CreateAssetServlet#0}
  1 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Applying Error filters
  1 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
  1 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_START{handleError:status=400}
  2 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{1,handleError:status=400} Using handler /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/default.jsp
  3 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html],order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@1df6f3d2), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@40016f5c), Config(type=contentsync, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@1e3621d8), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
  4 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{3,handleError:status=400} Error handler finished
  4 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{3,com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.CreateAssetServlet#0}
  4 (2014-02-17 02:02:29) TIMER_END{4,Request Processing} Request Processing
```

Answer (score 0):

When moving assets with huge size, it is better to use WebDAV by configuring it in ur system [1.New network connection in XP ; 2.Map network drive for windows 7] or any webDAV client like Bitkinex [http://www.bitkinex.com/download] for windows, cyberduck, webdrive for mac/ioS.

Suggest you to also refer http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/dam_upload_asset.html and http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/dam_media_handlers.html